# What are ways to approach working with GeoTiffs on Android?

Tags: android, tiff, android-2.2-froyo, geotiff

Seeing that there are a few `Android` applications that claim they can load `GeoTiff` files, it is obviously possible, but how should I approach gaining support for working with `GeoTiff` files on an Android device? By support I want to be able to read in and display `GeoTiff` files while accessing their tagged qualities.

Is the only way for this going with the `Android SDK` and an existing `C/C++ library`? If so, what should I look into?